# Why there is no table under schema on Mysql workbench navigation bar?

Tags: mysql, datatables, mysql-workbench

I have just executed *.sql* files successfully  and when I checked navigation bar, realized there is no any table under schema. Do you know what happened in here?

Answer (score -1):

In navigation bar, left click on 'tables' under schema and select refresh all. That is it!